# Unable to mock a method of an object with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I can't seem to mock a method of an object using jest.

The following code below will show a successful test when you run the command `jest -- Feature.test.js`

```
// ------ Feature.js
import Helper from './Helper';
const Feature = (arg1) => {
    const helper = new Helper();
    return helper.isValid(arg1 === 1, 'other');
    ;
};
export default Feature;



-------------------------------------------

// ------ Feature.test.js
//import Helper from './Helper';
import Feature from './Feature';

//jest.mock('./Helper');
describe('Feature', () => {
it('test', ()=>{
    //const helper = new Helper();
    //helper.isValid.mockReturnValue(true);
    const result = Feature('fake value');
    console.log(result);
    expect(result.toString()).toBe('false');
});
});
```

But the moment I uncomment the lines in `Feature.test.js` like so:

```
// ------ Feature.test.js
import Helper from './Helper';
import Feature from './Feature';

jest.mock('./Helper');
describe('Feature', () => {
it('test', ()=>{
    const helper = new Helper();
    helper.isValid.mockReturnValue(true);
    const result = Feature('fake value');
    console.log(result);
    expect(result.toString()).toBe('false');
});
});
```

and `jest -- Feature.test.js` again, I get this output:

```
> jest "Feature.test.js"

  console.log
    undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (./Feature.test.js:11:13)

 FAIL  ./Feature.test.js
  Feature
    ✕ test (21 ms)

  ● Feature › test

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

      10 |     const result = Feature('fake value');
      11 |     console.log(result);
    > 12 |     expect(result.toString()).toBe('false');
         |                   ^
      13 | });
      14 | });
      15 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (./Feature.test.js:12:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.564 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /Feature.test.js/i.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! john@1.0.0 test: `jest "Feature.test.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the anzen@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why won't my mock return a value?  What's the correct way to mock a method of an object being used in a module?

Comment: I didn't see any mock statements such as `jest.mock()`

Comment: @slideshowp2 - i editted my question and mid-way through the page to show my use of `jest.mock`.

Answer (score 0):

This shows example of how to mock a method of an object:

```
import Helper from './Helper';
import Feature from './Feature';

describe('Feature', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(Helper.prototype, 'isValid').mockImplementation(() => true);
    });

    it('test1', () => {
        const result = Feature('fake value');
        console.log(result);
        expect(result.toString()).toBe('true');
    });

    it('test2', () => {
        const result = Feature(1);
        console.log(result);
        expect(result.toString()).toBe('true');
    });

});
```